# Can an AZURE App Service be defined as part of a VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In AWS we can define a Serverless App within a VPC. Need not be the case but is considered obviously a good practise.

Can the same be done for an AZURE App Service? I.e. can an AZURE App Service be defined as part of a VNET?

Comment: Yes, you can [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

Comment: I was just about to read that. But is that the same as making it part of a VNET and able to deliver a cloud template for all this? A cursory scan made me think not, but I am more from an AWS background. @rickvdbosch

Comment: Take a read through of this article, it should answer your question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features

Comment: @silent   OK will do, 19 min read. thx

Comment: With the risk of slipping into chat: are you looking for having a template for always putting _any_ newly created App Service in a VNet, or are you looking for putting/updating a _specific_ App Service into a _specific_ VNet? And we'll need a bit more info on your requirements to do so, so we can nudge you in the right direction. Also: goedemiddag 

Comment: @rickvdbosch  chat is fine. All I want to do is for a small number of customers - say 10, give them all their own VNET with all their resources just for them so we need not consider multi-tenancy aspects. All this under a common AZURE account because billing is a fixed fee for a service. In AWS you can do this I know,  but with AZURE?  This steer is not from me but from others.

Comment: @rickvdbosch jazeker

Comment: @rickvdbosch  all those resources in the VNET are exactly the same.

Comment: @rickvdbosch  just to keep it simple, Event Hub --> AZ func --> COSMOS DB. All their own resources within their own VNET. App Service is just a little different.

Comment: Based on this, my approach would be to create one (parameterizable) [ARM template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) (or [Bicep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) file) to enable you to create/update the resources in a repeatable way as needed. As far as VNET information goes, have a look at the article linked in [silent's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833608/can-an-azure-app-service-be-defined-as-part-of-a-vnet?noredirect=1#comment121649311_68833608). You should be good to go!

Comment: @rickvdbosch  OK, thanks for that - post an answer I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of segments to answer your question. Here goes ...

#### VNet integration

Yes, you can [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

> With Azure Virtual Network (VNets), you can place many of your Azure resources in a non-internet-routable network. The VNet Integration feature enables your apps to access resources in or through a VNet. VNet Integration doesn't enable your apps to be accessed privately.
>
> Azure App Service has two variations:
>
> - The multitenant systems that support the full range of pricing plans except Isolated.
> - The App Service Environment, which deploys into your VNet and supports Isolated pricing plan apps.

If you're looking for restricting access to the App Services, the article linked in [silent's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833608/can-an-azure-app-service-be-defined-as-part-of-a-vnet?noredirect=1#comment121649311_68833608) is a good read. Especially the [Access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#access-restrictions) chapter.

> Access restrictions let you filter *inbound* requests. The filtering action takes place on the front-end roles that are upstream from the worker roles where your apps are running. Because the front-end roles are upstream from the workers, you can think of access restrictions as network-level protection for your apps.

#### Infrastructure as Code

The blueprint (or 'cloud template') you're talking about in the comments feels like you need Infrastructure as Code to build/maintain resources for customers that all have the same structure. And while Azure has a service that's called [Azure Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview), I think that would be overkill for the requirements you're giving.

> Azure Blueprints enables cloud architects and central information technology groups to define a repeatable set of Azure resources that implements and adheres to an organization's standards, patterns, and requirements. Azure Blueprints makes it possible for development teams to rapidly build and stand up new environments with trust they're building within organizational compliance with a set of built-in components, such as networking, to speed up development and delivery.

I think you could implement what you're looking for by creating a (parameterizable) [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) file to enable you to create/update the resources in a repeatable way as needed.

> Bicep is a domain-specific language (DSL) that uses declarative syntax to deploy Azure resources. It provides concise syntax, reliable type safety, and support for code reuse. We believe Bicep offers the best authoring experience for your infrastructure-as-code solutions in Azure.

Comment: Somehow AWS seems easier to follow. Misschien meer een geval van bekendheid.

Comment: I found out the web app can get a different name, obviously, per resource group. So what we want is possible.